# Create an array from a byte in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a byte like : 10010111 and I want to create an array from this.

[1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1] after this I have to reach every bit. I can not use bitget function.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: What format is your *byte* in? A string? A double?

Comment: I guess it is double.
de2bi(a(i,j)) returns 10010111

Comment: But doesn't `de2bi` already return an array?? Please be explicit about what you have and what you want

Comment: is de2bi returns an array?

Comment: Yes: http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/de2bi.html Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried but exactly I reach the every bit. How can I do that?

Comment: What does that mean? How can you address an individual element of a vector in Matlab?? For that, I have to say you need to do a basic Matlab tutorial I'm afraid.

Comment: I am trying to learn. Thank you for help Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a string then:

```
'10010111' == '1'   %//Returns a logical array
```

or

```
'10010111' - '0'    %//Returns a double array
```

If it's a double then:

```
dec2bin(151) == '1'  %// or - '0'
```

And finally if you literally have the number `10010111` (which I doubt) then you can do:

```
num2str(10010111) - '0' %// or == '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `x` be your input, a number or string

Then desired result can be obtained from :

`res=arrayfun(@str2num,num2str(x)); % num2str can be omitted if x is string`